# Iterate vector of pairs

Tags: vector, std-pair

I have vector1 [1,2,5,4,7].
I have another vector2 [(1,1),(2,5),(3,6),(4,7)].
I want to check if the element in Vector1 is the first or second element in the pair vector2. 
this is the code snippet. Any better approach other than this which takes less time ?

```
std::vector<int> vector1;
std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> vector2;
for(int i=0; i<vector1.size(); i++){
  for(int j=0; j<vector2.size(); j++){
      if(vector1[i] == vector2[j].first){
         //do something
            }
      else if(vector1[i] == vector2[j].second){
         //do something
            }
      else if((vector1[i] == vector2[j].first) && (vector1[i] == vector2[j].second)){
         //do something
            }
     }
}
```

Comment: There is no need for the second loop (with `j`)

Comment: I have edited the code. There was a typo. Can you check again and tell if the second loop still is not required and if so Why isn't it required ?? Thanks

Comment: Should it check for every item in `vector1`, whether it it is the first and/or second item of any pair in `vector2`?

Comment: Yes. You are right. All items of vector 1 has to be checked.

Comment: If the order of the vectors does not matter, one way would be to sort `vector1`, and for each item in `vector2` (2 for each pair), do a dichotomic search in `vector1`.
Or use multithreading to parallelize the outer loop.